# Trouble with function alias in PS module

Tags: powershell

I have a script module, where some of the functions were named "pluraly". For example, I was using "Get-Devices". Now I want to make the module follow PowerShell's naming better, by removing the letter 's', but I don't want to break exising scripts. So I added the following bit of code at the bottom of the function:

```
New-Alias -Name Get-LogicMonitorDevice -Value Get-LogicMonitorDevices -Force
Export-ModuleMember -Alias *
```

That worked great, so I started updating more of the functions in the module and have run into at least two, where I can import the module, and see the commands in the list of exported commands, but when I try to run it, PS says:

> Get-LogicMonitorAlertRule : The term 'Get-LogicMonitorAlertRules' is
>   not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Looking at the psm1 file, I see only one instance of:

```
New-Alias -Name Get-LogicMonitorAlertRule -Value Get-LogicMonitorAlertRules -Force
```

Finally, Get-LogicMonitorDevice still works. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you loading the functions the aliases are pointing to as part of the module import?  There's something missing here.

Comment: Yeah, I run Import-Module LogicMonitor, which does not return any errors and I am able to tab-complete the command name, but get that error.

Comment: What does `Get-Command -Module LogicMonitor` return after the import?  Sounds like some members aren't making it.  Please add this output to your question.

Comment: Did you try running `Import-Module LogicMonitor -Force`?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a caching issue. I actually closed my session and the issue went away with a new session.

Answer (score 0):

Re-opened my PowerShell session.